# Force nginx to verify upstream certs

Tags: ssl, nginx

I am trying to institute TLS at every layer of a proxying path. What I'm seeing is Nginx allowing an upstream to have a self-signed certificate. Is there any way to lock the authorities that are accepted when passing traffic to an upstream?

```
end-user  --1-->  nginx01  --2-->  nginx02  --N-->  nginxN
```

nginx01 has a trusted cert and the end-user connects without issue.
nginx02 has a self-signed cert, and when I proxy_pass to https://nginx02 I don't see any complaints in end-user browser or in nginx01 logs. I would expect a rejection.
If I curl nginx02 from nginx01 as expected I get the ssl rejection.

Is there any way to force nginx01 to validate nginx02 certs?

CentOS 7 running nginx 1.6.3-8.

```
/etc/hosts
10.21.10.99 upstream.example.com

curl https://upstream.example.com
# ssl rejection

curl https://upstream.example.com --cacert ./upstream.example.com.crt
# works fine (200)

# nginx configuration
server {
  listen 443;
  ssl on;
  ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/security/full_chain.crt;
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/security/ingress.example.com.key;
  server_name ingress.example.com;
  location / {
    proxy_pass https://upstream.example.com;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use

```
proxy_ssl_verify on;
proxy_ssl_trusted_certificate /path/to/your_selfsigned_ca_cert.pem
```

For additional details you can refer to nginx proxy docs [here](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_ssl_verify)

Answer (score 0):

I just needed to upgrade to get some proxy_ssl directives. 
http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_ssl_verify